# Cascading Dropdown lists with SPServices not working

Tags: jquery, spservices

I have a list called BRM with the following fields:
BRM (Text)
Country (List)
Business (List)

The country list is simple:
http://screencast.com/t/uh93fIhzWn

The business list is also simple:
http://screencast.com/t/ziRvT3khdyH

In the BRM I have this, but the business is not getting filtered:
http://screencast.com/t/S1hPETTDa

The spservices code that I have is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Documentos compartidos/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Documentos compartidos/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
   relationshipList: "Negocio",
   relationshipListParentColumn: "Pais",
   relationshipListChildColumn: "Negocio",
   debug: true
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you omitted parentColumn and childColumn. This needs to be present for the script to work, otherwise it doesn't know what fields on the form to manipulate.

> **parentColumn**  The DisplayName of the parent column in the form
>
> **childColumn**  The DisplayName of the child column in the form

Correct code should be:

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
   relationshipList: "Negocio",
   relationshipListParentColumn: "Pais",
   relationshipListChildColumn: "Negocio",
   parentColumn: "Pais", //the parent column name on BRM
   childColumn: "Negocio", // the child column on BRM
   debug: true
  });
```

Also, make sure the relationship columns are using the correct static/internal name.

[Cascading dropdowns documentation on CodePlex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: now it doesnt return anything, I also tried changing relationShipList by Pais, and its not working

Comment: at least it filters to 0 items on the second list, so we are close I guess

Comment: is the "business list" above called Negocio? Whatever the list name in screenshot #2 should be the relationshipList value.

Comment: I noticed they changed the Title column to Negocio, and the documentation says static column name. that was the problem thanks a lot !

Comment: ah yes, static name on the relationship columns, I was assuming they were correct, but if they were renamed the static name is Title.