# How to Filter the column Person or Group type in SP Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I create one list form i take customer column external data type column when user select this customer next column is users Person or Group type in this users only those users select which is related to 1st selected customer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cascading Dropdown lists with SPServices not working](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136938/cascading-dropdown-lists-with-spservices-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

1. Maintain separate list for 1st (parent list) dropdown values.
2. Add these parent list values as a lookup column in the Main list.
3. Use spservices method to achieve cascading dropdown.

Edit your form and insert below code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/address to document library/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/address to document library/jquery.SPServices-0.4.8.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
   relationshipList: "Cities",
   relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
   relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
   parentColumn: "Country",
   childColumn: "City",
   debug: true
  });
 });
</script>
```

Note: **Replace country, city and title with your list name**

Reference: [Read More](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/01/cascading-drop-down-using-jquery.html)

Comment: I have one query can i filter the Person or Group type column value in SP2013?

Comment: I create one list form  i take customer column external data type column when user select this customer next column is users  Person or Group type   in this users only those users select which is related to 1st selected customer

Comment: It is not allowed to show Person or Group type as a Dropdown/lookup. Please share your list schema